# Spring Java WebSockets Messaging between users

Tags: java, spring, websocket

This is question about websockets and architecture of messaging between users. What i've done:

Client side:
Send message to server with parameter - conversation uuid.  And also i subscribed to topic where new messages must be appeared.

Server side:
When i receive message with conversation uuid, i launch scheduler which sends new messages for conversation to topic.

But there alot of conversation could be, so i my controller class i got field of class "conversationSchedulers" - it is HashMap where key is a username and value is current scheduler which sends new messages for conversation. When user wants to recieve new messages for other conversation, he click on conversation in web application and next code works:

Cliend side:
Send messages with new conversation uuid.

Server side:
Gain previous running scheduler - if it is - cancel it, and run new scheduler with new conversation uuid.

And everything is works... when there are ONE tab with messages. When user open two or more tabs - all architecture gone to the hell. Because i accept only one scheduler for messaging... only one conversation could be opened.

In that moment i got an idea - accept many schedulers to messaging with more than one user at the same time, but i did not do this implementation because on messaging page i have got a button to write a NEW message, when user want to write new message all new messages from other users must stop to sends to client, but i can not stop them because user got a two tabs. Stop all schedulers that means stop messaging on all tabs. And this is a problem. May be i choose wrong architecture? Or websockets it is a bad idea for such task?

Comment: Check out the link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34929578/spring-websocket-sendtosession-send-message-to-specific-session