# Cannot send user message with Spring Websocket

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, websocket, spring-websocket

I read Spring docs about user destinations.
I would like to use `convertAndSendToUser` method to send a message only to a particular user.

This is the java code:

```
@Controller
public class WebsocketTest {

    @Autowired
    public SimpMessageSendingOperations messagingTemplate;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        ScheduledExecutorService statusTimerExecutor=Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        statusTimerExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {                
            @Override
            public void run() {
                messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser("myuser","/queue/test", new Return("test"));
            }
        }, 5000,5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```

This is the client js code:

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/hello');
            stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);            
            stompClient.connect("myuser","mypass", function(frame) {
                setConnected(true);
                console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
                stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function(greeting){
                    showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).value);
                });
                stompClient.subscribe('/user/queue/test', function(greeting){
                    showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).value);
                });
            });
```

First of all is it correct to conside the user value this one?

stompClient.connect("**myuser**",...

Why this test doesn't work? This user did not receveive any message.
If I switch destination to `/topic/greetings` and change method to `convertAndSend()` this works, but obviously as broadcast and not only to particular user as requested.

### **Little update**

I tried to setup a reply to single user with this code:

```
    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendToUser("/queue/test")
    public Return test(){
        return new Return("test");
    }
```

This works, this is not what I need becase this reply only to a message from client. Seems that I cannot use `convertAndSendToUser()` for unsollicited messaged from server.

Answer (score 1):

Subscribing to `/user/queue/test` on the client side and using `convertAndSendToUser` to send a message to the `/topic/test` topic looks about right.

Now how are you getting the `"myUser"` value?

You can get this value from either `request.getUserPrincipal()` during the handshake, or inject the `Principal` when receiving a message; the sessionId works as well here. You can check [this commit for more details on the matter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/97fb308b6bbedd8cd79b9de04ee0fa2c0c431bb4).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe its late to answer the question but for the people who may face similar issue, here is what I was missing: 
The websocket URL which you are connecting to should also be a secured URL. If its not then there is no mapping between the user and the session and hence you are not able to send message to the user using `convertAndSendToUser()`.

So, for e.g. you are connecting to the endpoint with URL pattern `/hello` then it should be a secured one.