# Java STOMP message not received for the target session

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, stomp

Im trying to implement simple application in which unauthenticated users can just type in a group name and send message to group.

Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSockConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws-reg").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/all","/personal");
    }
}
```

Controller

```
    @Controller
    public class HomeController {
        @Autowired
        private SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;

        private final Map<String, List<String>> groupSessions = new HashMap<>();

        @MessageMapping("/group/{groupName}/join")
        public void joinGroup(@DestinationVariable String groupName, SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor) {
            groupSessions.computeIfAbsent(groupName, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(headerAccessor.getSessionId());

        }
        @MessageMapping("/group/{groupName}/send")
        public void sendToGroup(@DestinationVariable String groupName, Message<String> message) throws IOException {
            for ( String  session : groupSessions.get(groupName)){
                simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(session,"/personal",message.getPayload());
            }
        }
    }
```

JavaScript in HTML

```
<script>
        const socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/ws-reg');

        const stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

        function joinGroup() {
            const groupName = document.getElementById('groupInput').value;

            stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
                setConnected(true);
                console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
                stompClient.subscribe('/personal', function(greeting){
                    console.log(JSON.parse(greeting.body));
                });
            });

            stompClient.send(`/app/group/${groupName}/join`, {}, JSON.stringify({}));
        }

        function sendMessage() {
            const groupName = document.getElementById('groupInput').value;
            const messageContent = document.getElementById('messageInput').value;
            stompClient.send(`/app/group/${groupName}/send`, {}, JSON.stringify({ content: messageContent }));
        }
 </script>
```

FE view
[image]

My expectation :

user one : type in 'group1' and joins

user two : type in 'group1' and joins

user three: type 'group2' and joins

When user one sends a message it should pass to websocket for user one and and two only.

While debugging there is no logs of new message or any events in websockets of any users. sendToGroup method was triggered and session id is not null

EDIT:
By following this [Spring session + Spring web socket. Send message to specific client based on session id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43536507/spring-session-spring-web-socket-send-message-to-specific-client-based-on-ses)
I have updated the code like this to send message, But still not working

```
 SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = SimpMessageHeaderAccessor
                    .create(SimpMessageType.MESSAGE);
            headerAccessor.setSessionId(session);
            headerAccessor.setLeaveMutable(true);

simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(session,"/personal",message.getPayload(),headerAccessor.getMessageHeaders());
```

However by this code, message is received at all websocket instances

```
simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/personal",message.getPayload(),headerAccessor.getMessageHeaders());
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and using `setAllowedOriginPatterns` worked for me. I have altered your code; try this, it should work.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSockConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
       registry.addEndpoint("/wsreg").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/all","/personal");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, But did not solved the issue

Comment: Add debugs to check whether the joinGroup correctly adds data to your Hashmap, it might be an issue related to it.

Comment: Yes,  it was already checked, and Session variable passed to convertAndSendToUser() is also not null

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when we use `convertAndSendToUser()` method, We need to add `/user` to the subscription path, in case of my example

Change

```
 stompClient.subscribe('/personal', function(greeting){
                    console.log(JSON.parse(greeting.body));
                });
```

To

```
stompClient.subscribe('/user/personal', function(greeting){
                    console.log(JSON.parse(greeting.body));
                });
```

But doing this alone did not fixed my case

So there is an alternate way to achieve this, Which i tested and its working.

Instead of using session id,  we will use the username to be passed to `convertAndSendToUser()`

To achieve this,

First create a `HandShakeHandler`

```
public class CustomHandShakeHandler  extends DefaultHandshakeHandler {
    @Override
    protected Principal determineUser(ServerHttpRequest request,
                                      WebSocketHandler wsHandler,
                                      Map<String, Object> attributes) {
        return new UserPrincipal(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    }
}
```

And Add this in Config

```
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws-reg")
                .setHandshakeHandler(new CustomHandShakeHandler())
                .withSockJS();
    }
```

At last, all we need to do is instead of using session id, use the principal username.
This username will be accessible from `headerAccessor.getUser().getName()`  at `joinGroup()` method

Also no need to send SimpMessageHeaderAccessor  data in `convertAndSendToUser()` method.