# Spring WebSocket convertAndSendToUser to specific sessionID

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-websocket, stomp

As this [quetion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34929578/spring-websocket-sendtosession-send-message-to-specific-session), I want to send to a specific user with its sessionID.

And I try the answer's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35020070/5528589) but the client side still not receiving the message.

These are my setting.

I save user's sessionID when they connect to the server

```
@EventListener
private void handleSessionConnected(SessionConnectEvent event) {
    SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headers = SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.wrap(event.getMessage());
    String username = headers.getNativeHeader("login").get(0);

    String sessionId = headers.getSessionId();

    User user = new User(username, sessionId);

    participantRepository.add(user);

    Success", headers.getMessageHeaders());
}
```

The **broadcast message handler** in *Controller*

```
@MessageMapping("/chat")
public void handleChat(ChatMessage message, SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor) throws Exception{
    logger.debug(">>>[CHAT MESSAGE]");
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

    String jsonMessage = gson.toJson(message);
    JsonObject jsonObMessage = 
    parser.parse(jsonMessage).getAsJsonObject().get("map").getAsJsonObject();

    messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/queue", message);

}
```

The **private message handler** in *Controller*

```
@MessageMapping("/chat.{user}")
public void handlePrivateChat(@Payload ChatMessage message, SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor) throws Exception{
    logger.debug(">>>[PRIVATE CHAT MESSAGE]");

    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    SimpMessageHeaderAccessor responseAccessor = SimpMessageHeaderAccessor
            .create(SimpMessageType.MESSAGE);

    String jsonMessage = gson.toJson(message);
    JsonObject jsonObMessage = 
    parser.parse(jsonMessage).getAsJsonObject().get("map").getAsJsonObject();

    User toUser = activeUsers.getByName(jsonObMessage.get("to").getAsString());
    String destinateSessionID = toUser.getSessionID();
    responseAccessor.setSessionId(destinateSessionID);
    responseAccessor.setLeaveMutable(true);
    MessageHeaders responseMessageHeader =  responseAccessor.getMessageHeaders();

    if(toUser != null){
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(destinateSessionID, "/queue", message, responseMessageHeader);
    }

}
```

Both message handler could get the message but the client could only get the broadcast message.
Still couldn't find the answer. Hope someone could help me. Thx.

**Update**

In my **WebSocketConfig**

```
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/queue", "/topic");
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}
```

Comment: You should post some more of your code, i.e. your WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer. But the behavior when spring establishes the username mapping for the websocket is either at spring security level, or you need to declare a handshakeInterceptor where you populate the spring SecurityContextHolder. The userName used by method convertAndSendToUser is the principal of the object that is in spring SecurityContextHolder

Comment: But as this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34929578/spring-websocket-sendtosession-send-message-to-specific-session/35020070#35020070), it doesn't need the user to get authenticated. How does it work? I just update my config to my question. I could get the broadcast message from "/queue" but no private message.