# How to send websocket message to a specific subscription in a session?

Tags: java, websocket, spring-websocket, stomp, spring-messaging

I have implemented a WebSocket server using Spring WebSocket and STOMP. There are multiple subscriptions over a single session and I want to send message to a specific subscription only.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Client connects to server by calling registered STOMP endpoint.
   [image]
2. Client makes 2 subscription over the connection.

```
SUBSCRIBE
country:germany
id:sub-0
destination:/user/queue/countryUpdates
```

```
SUBSCRIBE
country:france
id:sub-1
destination:/user/queue/countryUpdates
```

3. In SimpUserRegistry there is 1 user and 1 session with 2 subscription.[image]
4. Problem is if I send a message to one subscription it's send to other subscription as well.[image]
5. At the time of sending the message I am adding subscription id in native headers, but it's not working.

```
SimpMessageHeaderAccessor accessor = SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.create(SimpMessageType.MESSAGE);
accessor.setNativeHeader("id", subscriptionId);
accessor.setNativeHeader("subscription", subscriptionId);
accessor.setSubscriptionId(subscriptionId);
accessor.setLeaveMutable(true);
messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(simpUserId, REPLY_DESTINATION, message, accessor.getMessageHeaders());
```

What I've tried: If I add country to destination, each subscription have unique destination than there are no duplicate messages.

I want to use id/subscriptionId to determine the subscription and send message to that particular subscription.

Comment: Anyways, I had to use different destination in subscription as it was working properly.

Comment: possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60488396/how-to-send-message-to-a-specific-subscription-over-spring-websocket-stomp).

I have been trying to solve the same issue, the (self-)answer to the duplicate doesn't manage to go further than sending to _session_ (rather than subscription)